# How can I read a file, put contents in an array, shuffle the array, and then write the shuffled array to the file in python 2.7

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, file

I am working on something. Here's what the code needs to do

1. Read the file
2. Put every line into an item in an array
3. Shuffle the array into as many possible shuffles it can. Will explain below
4. Create a new file to store the shuffled words

Number 3 explained:
file.txt contains the following

```
this
is
a
test
```

It would need to shuffle to any possible outcome. Like this

```
this is a test
this a is test
this test is a
this test a is
```

And so on and so forth. There is 16 possible outcomes, so I'm not going to flood my question with it.

---

I am using the following code in Python 2.7

```
file = raw_input('Enter File Name: ')
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    array = list(f)
    print array
```

The output is this, which is completely okay(except the '\n'):

```
['this\n', 'is\n', 'a\n', 'test']
```

Now, whenever I use the shuffle(), I'm using this code

```
from random import shuffle
file = raw_input('Enter File Name: ')
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    array = list(f)
    new = shuffle(array)
    print new
```

The output is this:

```
None
```

I know in order to write, I need to use w+ and do f.write(new) then f.close(), it clears my file.txt and saves it blank

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't there be 4! = 24 possibilities rather than 16? In any event -- are you familiar with `itertools`?

Comment: Oh yeah. You're right, I did 4*4 rather than the factorial. Anyway, I'm not. I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> words = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
>>> for p in itertools.permutations(words): print ' '.join(p)

this is a test
this is test a
this a is test
this a test is
this test is a
this test a is
is this a test
is this test a
is a this test
is a test this
is test this a
is test a this
a this is test
a this test is
a is this test
a is test this
a test this is
a test is this
test this is a
test this a is
test is this a
test is a this
test a this is
test a is this
```

Obviously, the prints can be replaced by writes to a file.

If the input file isn't too large, you can replace loops with comprehensions and use whole-file reads and writes:

```
import itertools

with open('test.txt','r') as infile, open('shuffles.txt','w') as outfile:
    words = infile.read().strip().split('\n')
    shuffles = itertools.permutations(words)
    output = '\n'.join(' '.join(shuffle) for shuffle in shuffles)
    outfile.write(output)
```

Comment: This helps a lot, but I'm running into another problem. The file should be opened already, no? http://prntscr.com/b41vh1

Comment: Yes, open the target file for writing before looping through the permutations. Close it afterwards.